# Sending a properly email with line breaks

Tags: powershell

I am attempting to send the log files contents in the body of an email using `Send-MailMessage.` I tried using  `` `r`n `` to no effect.

My email in outlook looks like the following....

[image]

My desired mail output  :

[image]

Here is my script :

```
$SourceDir = "C:\Temp\"
#$GCI_Fiter = '*.txt'
$Include=@("*.log","*.txt")

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $SourceDir -Include "$Include" -File

$myvar = @()
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList)   {
#$FLI_Content = Get-Content -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
#$ExceptionLines = $FLI_Content | Select-String 'Exception' | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString().Trim()}
#if ($FLI_Content Get-Content -Path $file.FullName | Select-String "Exception" )
#){

$results = Get-Content -Path $FL_Item.FullName | Select-String "Exception"

if ($results) {
    Write-Host "$($FL_Item.FullName) Exception found." -BackgroundColor Cyan
    #$myvar += $results
    $LINE = "$($FL_Item.Name)" + ":"
    $EMAILBODY = $LINE + "`r`n"
    $myvar += $EMAILBODY + $results + "`r`n"
    Write-Output "Exception found"
}
else {
    Write-Host "$($FL_Item.FullName) No exception found." -BackgroundColor Green
    Write-Output "No exception found"
}

#}
#$ExceptionLines = $FLI_Content | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Exception olustu'
#$ExceptionLines = $FLI_Content | Select-String -SimpleMatch 'Exception' | ForEach-Object {$_.ToString().Trim()}
#$FLI_Content

}

return $myvar


        $MailBody = "Hi,`r

        Exception logs. `r

        "+$myvar+"

        `r  
        `r
        Regards,
        "

Send-MailMessage -to $emailto -Subject $subject -SmtpServer $smtp -From $fromaddress -Body $MailBody -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8) -Credential $creds
```

Comment: I think just doubling up `'r'n` to `'r'n'r'n` (with back ticks as you already have not single quotes) for the lines starting: `$EMAILBODY =` and `$myvar +=` lines might do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application`. I have come across a similar case. If you are using Outlook for example use the below code, however you format the email in the $Mail.Body, that is how they will receive the email.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$Mail = $Outlook.CreateItem(0)
$Mail.To = "usermail@something.com"
$Mail.Subject = "Powershell"
$Mail.Body ="email text here"
$Date = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMdd")
$File = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\log$Date.csv"
$Mail.Attachments.Add($File)
$Mail.Send()
```